# JSF Exception: /main.jsp not found in external context as a Resource

Tags: jsf, facelets, icefaces

I have a User Interface built using "IceFaces". And it's deployed on  a portal built using "LifeRay". The UI application is getting undeployed automatically from the portal sometimes.
And the log is showing the following error message :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.Exception: javax.faces.FacesException: Problem in renderResponse: /main.jsp Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:175) 
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) 
       ----------------- 
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: javax.faces.FacesException: Problem in renderResponse: /main.jsp Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource 
        at com.icesoft.faces.context.View.servePage(View.java:136) 
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.MultiViewServer.service(MultiViewServer.java:55)
       ------------------ 
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Problem in renderResponse: /main.jsp Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource 
        at com.icesoft.faces.facelets.D2DFaceletViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DFaceletViewHandler.java:296) 
        at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderView(D2DViewHandler.java:153) 
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:109) 
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /main.jsp Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource 
        at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:121) 
        at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:91) 
        at com.icesoft.faces.facelets.D2DFaceletViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DFaceletViewHandler.java:268)
        ... 171 more
```

The UI has only `.xhtml` pages and no jsp page so I have no idea why it's trying to render a main`.jsp` page. 
Also, after it gets deployed again it works fine for some time before the exception resurfaces.

Will be grateful if you can provide any pointer to the root cause or how to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the following in your web.xml?

```
   <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
      <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
   </context-param>
```